# Reveal Elemen on Touch / Click exept on Link Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to reveal element if i touch screen but not if im clicking link

```
setInterval(function() {
   $('#mydiv').removeClass('showme');
}, 3000);
$('html').click(function() {
   $('#mydiv').addClass('showme');
});
```

im using that code, element dissapear every 3sec and appear after im clicking my screen. the problem is when im clicking link or image, that #mydiv will Shown.

Answer (score 0):

ive got my answer, thanks to my self

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('#mydiv').removeClass('showme');
}, 3000);
$('html').click(function() {
    $('#2top').addClass('showme');
});
$("a[href]").click(function() {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```